# Guice how to rebind annotated constant to another name?

Tags: java, guice

Say I have a value bound to a string annotated with "xxx" in some module, but I'd like to have this constant available from another annotation name (say "yyy"). Is there anyway I can give a synonym like this?

For example, some module contains:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("xxx")).to("testing");
```

I want to write something like:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("yyy")).to(value of xxx);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [`ConstantBindingBuilderImpl.java`](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/ConstantBindingBuilderImpl.java#L55) you'll see it's just syntactic sugar for inferring the binding type from the primitive. Guice doesn't let you bind a constant to another binding, but it does let you bind a "normal" binding to another binding.

```
bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("yyy"))
    .to(Key.get(String.class, Names.named("xxx")));
```

This looks like it is less useful than `bindConstant()`, because you have to specify the type of binding explicitly, but the reality is that `bindConstant()` quietly does that for you behind the scenes anyway. (By the way, String elements in Guice are a little magic--if you've bound an annotation to a String you can [inject it as a variety of other primitive types](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/InjectorImpl.java#L438). This is why [`Names.bindProperties`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/name/Names.html) can inject a variety of types, not just Strings.)

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. I had to do: `bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("yyy")).to(Key.get(String.class, Names.named("xxx")));` however. `annotatedWith` was not a method of the object returned by `.to(String.class)`.